# Django Admin Form Not Showing All Instance Data

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My django admin form doesn't show the correct initial values for a given object's data. I've tried modifying the form to explicitly set the initial value on load, but that has no effect either. My code looks like this:

```
DISCOUNT_OVERRIDE_CHOICES = (
        (None, ""),
        (Decimal('10'), _('10%')),
        (Decimal('20'), _('20%')),
        (Decimal('30'), _('30%')),
        (Decimal('40'), _('40%')),
        (Decimal('50'), _('50%')),
    )
    self.fields['discount'].choices = \
            DISCOUNT_OVERRIDE_CHOICES

    if self.instance.discount:
        self.initial['discount'] = \
                self.instance.discount
```

The above code is part of a form that I later call with form = MyForm in the appropriate Admin model. What happens is that the admin page will load correctly and display all of the appropriate data, but the initial value of the "discount" field will always be the empty-string, None option, and never accurately represents the discount percentage stored with the object whose data populates the form. This field is the only field in which it happens too, and the problem persists even if I don't override the available choices (in that case, the 10% choice is always selected on page load)

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `discount` an instance of `models.DecimalField`?

Comment: Yea it is. Can I not set a None option in that case or something?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set an initial, as Django will always prepopulate the form with data from the instance on a `ModelForm`. Have you perhaps overridden the form, and in particular the `discount` field on the form? It must remain a `DecimalField` all the way through, or the value will not not be a `Decimal` type and, thus, won't match your choices.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is wrong

```
self.initial['discount'] = \
                self.instance.discount
```

You should do

```
self.fields['discount'].initial = \
                self.instance.discount
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried that as well, with the same results. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Since the above doesn't work somewhere else is your problem. You have to expose more bits of your code.

Comment: Also I hope that the code you pasted 'lives' inside the `__init__` of the form. Otherwise it has no meaning.